# worldpay useTemplateForm callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, payment-gateway, worldpay

I implemented worldpay on my onepage angular app (angular 1.x). Im using useTemplateForm() method to generate credit card form and retrive token. Everything is working fine, except that my callback function (that is set in useTemplateForm) is called multiple times after retriving token.

This is due to calling useTemplateForm every time payments window pops up. Worldpay.js somehow stacks those callbacks instead of clearing them and i have no idea how to prevent it. I have to call useTemplateForm every time window pops up cos the element (div) that contains iframe is destroyed every time payment window closes. Destroying this element doesnt reset stacked callbacks tho.

I can handle this in different ways, but id rather use some method to prevent stacking infinite amount of callbacks cos at the end it will just consume unnecessary resources.

Anyone got any idea how to "fix" this ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? @lab6

Comment: Nah, i just did some workaround not the perfect, but couldn't find a "correct" way.

Comment: @Iab6 Could you explain what your workaround was and add it as an answer? The only way round it so far is when I am finished/unmounting the worldpay form (I am using `react`)  I used `window.removeEventListener("message", window.Worldpay.template.messageListener, false);` and that seems to stop the stacking of callbacks i'll add this as an answer but its not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't think there is really a reliable solution to this, but I have found something that does stop the stacking of callbacks.

---

### Solution (nonprod)

If you remove the WorldPay event listener then your registered callback will no longer be called:

```
window.removeEventListener("message", Worldpay.template.messageListener, false);
```

***1) On Success Callback (not recommended)***
You could put this in the success callback of the `Worldpay.useTemplateForm` config if you always unload the `templateForm` on success:

```
'callback': function (obj) {
    window.removeEventListener("message", Worldpay.template.messageListener, false);
    worldPaySuccessCallBack(obj)
},
```

***2) When you have removed the WorldPay form from the DOM***
I don't have much experience with `Angular` but when you no longer have the `Worldpay` form rendered then I would call the `removeEventListener` line.

***3) On componentWillUnmount (react)***
I happen to to be running into this issue whilst using `react` so I put the `removeEventListener` line in the `componentWillUnmount` of my `Worldpay` component.

---

### Please note

The reason why I **do not recommend** taking this approach in production is because if you are loading your `WorldPay` library via the `cdn` (https://cdn.worldpay.com/v1/worldpay.js) then it is using a unversioned library.

Worldpay currently deploy updates to this url latest being:
`WorldpayJS v0.75.1 - Wed, 17 Jan 2018 12:10:44 GMT`

So the `Worldpay.template.messageListener` object path could change at any point if they are not following the normal `semver` rules.